# is there a way i can create such song requests and how can i make a signup and login profile?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, user-profile

hi I was wondering how do I go about creating something like this [http://coolvibes.hopto.org/uploads/requested.png] for a website I am currently making?

also I were wondering how do I go about making a user profile with MySQL and phpMyAdmin
using login page and two forms username and password
If not registered a signup up page and have there own profile after signup
and they would get there own little email upon signup saying something like welcome to stack overflow for example?

Comment: Sure.  Create a User table, a Song table, and an Artist table.  Create a Reference entity / value table so you can search songs by genre, album, or whatever else you think of.

Comment: ok i'm just learn my way through phpmyadmin could you possible give me a written tutorial so i know what i am doing please @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: Read [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/docs/) documentation.

Comment: so @GilbertLeBlanc i have created User, Song,  and  artist tables, were next